# eclipse plugin highlight class name in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In developing an Eclipse plugin, is there a way to modify the package explorer. Say I want to highlight/color a class name that has less than 200 lines code or add a text beside that file. is that possible to develop? or better is there an existing eclipse plugin that does that. Does anyone know a tutorial or a link to help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into writing a context menu action for the items in a navigation view (Navigator, Java Explorer, Package Explorer, etc.) that would validate the selected items (or their contained items if, for example, you've selected a package).  You could use markers to indicate which files (and the lines in those files) have issues that you've identified.

For an example of how to code to those API's, use the templates in the New Eclipse PLugin wizard.  There's a template for popup menu actions and a template for a builder.  The builder example shows how to validate multiple files and manage markers.